How to print fuctions save the arguments using sympy pprint?
For a function that depend on various variables, having it pretty print as u(x, y, z, w) is quite tedious to read when the result is long.
from sympy import *

init_printing()
x, y, z, w = symbols('x y z w')
u = Function('u')(x, y, z, w)
f = u.diff(x)
pprint(f)

It prints out
∂                
──(u(x, y, z, w))
∂x

Even though it is sensible, it is disturbing when there are many terms. How can it print just
∂                
──(u)
∂x


Note that this question has been asked before at How to pretty-print Sympy Functions without arguments? but did not receive any upvoted or accepted answers.

I see, I didn't manage to find that earlier. It seems to me sympy doesn't support it, and is being used for light calculation.
Have you an idea of other good libraries?

To accomplish your goal, you can use the following code:
.subs(u, Function('u')): Substitutes the symbol u with the function symbol Function('u') in the result. This effectively replaces the long function notation with just u without calling it.
from sympy import *

init_printing()
x, y, z, w = symbols('x y z w')
u = Function('u')(x, y, z, w)
f = u.diff(x)
pprint(f.subs(u, Function('u')))

The above may be wrong when printing u**n, it will be correct when changing Function('u') to Symbol('u').

from sympy import *

init_printing()
x, y, z, w = symbols('x y z w')
u = Function('u')(x, y, z, w)
f = u.diff(x)
pprint(f.subs(u, Symbol('u')))
f2 = u ** n
pprint(f2.subs(u, Symbol('u')))


That is a good way to reduce clutter, however it turns instances of u ** n into u(n)

I changed my answer, it is correct to print u ** n by using Symbol instead of Function.

You need to create a custom printer and modify the code that prints applied undefined functions. You can take a look at sympy.printing.pretty.pretty to have a basic idea. Here is my attempt:
from sympy.printing.pretty.pretty import PrettyPrinter
from sympy.printing.pretty.pretty_symbology import pretty_use_unicode
from sympy.core.function import AppliedUndef
from sympy.printing.conventions import requires_partial
from sympy.printing.pretty.stringpict import stringPict, prettyForm

class MyPrettyPrinter(PrettyPrinter):
    """Pretty printer customized to visualize applied undefined functions
    without arguments.
    """
    def __init__(self, settings=None):
        self._default_settings.update({
            "applied_func_with_no_args": True
        })
        super().__init__(settings)

    def _print_Function(self, expr, sort=False, func_name=None, left='(', right=')'):
        if isinstance(expr, AppliedUndef) and self._settings["applied_func_with_no_args"]:
            prettyFunc = self._print(Symbol(expr.func.__name__))
            prettyArgs = prettyForm("")
            pform = prettyForm(
                binding=prettyForm.FUNC, *stringPict.next(prettyFunc))
            # store pform parts so it can be reassembled e.g. when powered
            pform.prettyFunc = prettyFunc
            pform.prettyArgs = prettyArgs
            return pform
        
        return super()._print_Function(expr, sort=sort, func_name=func_name, left=left, right=right)

def my_pretty_printer(expr, **settings):
    """This function will be execute by IPython/Jupyter when we
    want to pretty print something on the screen. Let f be a function,
    if we execute f**2 on a cell, my_pretty_printer will be executed.
    """
    # NOTE: code modified from sympy.printing.pretty.pretty.pprint
    
    pp = MyPrettyPrinter(settings)
    
    # XXX: this is an ugly hack, but at least it works
    use_unicode = pp._settings['use_unicode']
    uflag = pretty_use_unicode(use_unicode)
    
    try:
        return pp.doprint(expr)
    finally:
        pretty_use_unicode(uflag)

def my_pretty(expr, **settings):
    """Use this function instead of pprint
    """
    print(my_pretty_printer(expr, **settings))

If you wish to reuse the above code, you can save it in a file, and whenever you need it you import my_pretty_printer and/or my_pretty.
Here is how to use my_pretty, which effectively replaces pprint:
from sympy import *
var("x, y, z")
f = Function("f")(x, y, z)
my_pretty(f)
# f

my_pretty(f**2)
#  2
# f 

my_pretty(f**2, applied_func_with_no_args=False)
#  2         
# f (x, y, z)

But if you are working on IPython/Jupyter, instead of calling my_pretty every time, you can just set up init_printing informing it that you want to use your custom printer, like this:
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex=False, use_pretty=True, pretty_printer=my_pretty_printer, applied_func_with_no_args=True)

var("x, y, z")
f = Function("f")(x, y, z)
f**2
#  2
# f 

Note that I set applied_func_with_no_args=True. Keywords arguments should get sent to my_pretty_printer in order to customize the printer. However, as of SymPy 1.13.2, this is not the case for pretty print. I believe this to be a bug.
